# Firefox web page reload when OS X wakes up

Tags: macos, firefox

When OS X wakes up from sleep and Firefox is open, every opened tab reloads. Is there a way to prevent Firefox from doing that? I have looked in about:config but have not seen anything obvious that might be related.

I don't think that it is version related, but here goes anyway.

OS X 10.6.2
Firefox 3.5.6

Comment: If Firefox is left open or when you open it after coming out of sleep?

Comment: It is open with a bunch of tabs when the machine goes to sleep

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  My installation is the exact same, Mac 10.6.2/Firefox 3.5.6 and I could swear it used to do that exact thing.  I just put my computer to sleep to make sure, and it didn't do it.  The only thing that was different this time was that it was plugged in to the office ethernet jack instead of using AirPort.

My hypothesis is that using wireless will trigger a reload because of the time lag between 'wake up' and network connectivity.  Is your computer plugged into a network or using wireless?

Comment: I am using wireless. I will try it using an ethernet cable to see what happens.

Comment: I have just finished trying sleep/wakeup with an Ethernet cable connection instead of AirPort and that seems to do the trick. FF did not reload every tab on wakeup.

And it also got rid of a the mysterious error 15006 message related to iTunes and AirTunes.

Well, I got myself a living room re-design project over the Christmas holidays....

Thanks for your suggestion.